# Call same action multiple times on form submit

Tags: model-view-controller, struts2

I have a requirement to call action A multiple times from action B in the same method call. Is there any way to achieve it?
I can give some background. I have a product specific API that is internally implemented with struts and the action can accept only one id and one file object. However, I have a requirement to store the same file for multiple ids. So can I use a custom action class that can receive multiple ids and in a loop call the action class that comes with the product. Also, can I pass the form data to the next action class through an interceptor

Comment: I'm no struts expert, but it sounds to me like there's business logic tightly coupled with a controller when it should be in a model.  The controller should invoke the business logic on the model, not on controller actions.

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Comment: @David We would typically say business/service layer because a struts2 action is a model (to both service and view layers) but yes that does seem like part of the issue.

Comment: Why don't you post some code? It might be possible to only use one action to do both. It might even be possible to use ajax to make what you have work already.

Answer (score 1):

You can Call same Action Class multiple times on form submit through different action names, something like deleteUser, editUser, addUser on Same UserAction class.

Hope, it will fulfil your purpose.

Comment: I have a file upload action. I do not want to submit the form multiple times as that would pass the file data multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it and probably dont have time to try it. But I think you can try this way  to call a single action multiple times. In struts.xml use redirect on success to same action name.Example

```
<action name="onSubmit" class="com.example.SubmitAction" method="upload">
<result name="success" type="redirect">onSubmit</result>
<result name="error">Success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

OR

```
<action name="onSubmit" class="com.example.SubmitAction" method="upload">
<result name="success" type="redirect">onSubmitRedirect</result>
<result name="error">Success.jsp</result>
</action>



<action name="onSubmitRedirect">
<result name="success" type="redirect">onSubmit</result>
</action>
```

You can use error condition to terminate you loop. Try it I will be glad to know its results.